# Azure terraform pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I hope somebody can help me to solve this issue and understand how to implement the best approach.

I have a production environment running tons of azure services (sql server, databases, web app etc).

all those infra has been created with terraform. For as powerful as it is, I am terrified on using it in a pipeline for 1 reason.

Some of my friend, often they do some changes to the infra manually, and having not having those changes in my terraform states, if I automate this process, it might destroy the resource ungracefully, which is something that I don't want to face.

so I was wondering if anyone can shade some light on the following question:

is it possible to have terraform automated to check the infra state at every push to GitHub, and to quit if the output of the plan reports any change?

change to make clear my example.

Lets say I have a terraform state on which I have 2 web app, and somebody manually created a 3 web app on that resource group, it develops some code and push it to GitHub.My pipeline triggers, and as first step I have terraform that runs a `terraform plan` and/or `terraform apply`, if this command reports any change, I want it to quit the pipeline(fail) so I will know there is something new there, and if the `terraform plan` and/or `terraform apply` return `there are no changes to the infra, is up to date` to continue with the code deployment.

thank you in advance for any help and clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just run

```
terraform plan -detailed-exitcode
```

If the exit code is != 0, you know there are changes. See [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/plan.html#other-options) for details.

Let me point out that I would highly advise you to lock down your prod environment so that nobody can do manual changes! Your CI/CD pipeline should be the only way to make changes there.

Comment: Thank amazing and a relief knowing this. Just one more question regarding this. If I set the terraform detailed-exit code, and there is a change, it will quit automatically or I have to set any configuration for it to stop the pipeline?

Comment: not sure tbh. Just give it a quick try. Will be easy to see

Comment: @NaydenVan did you try it out? Will a non-zero code stop the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer, you can also make use of terraform import command just to import the remote changes to your state file. The terraform import command is used to import existing resources into Terraform. Later run plan to check if the changes are in sync.

Refer: https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/import.html